# Given a parallelogram $ABCD,$ a line cuts of $AB/3, AD/4$ and $\lambda AC$ from segments $AB, AD$ and $AC.$ Find $\lambda.$

Tags: geometry

Given a parallelogram $ABCD,$ a line cuts of $AB/3, AD/4$ and $\lambda AC$ from segments $AB, AD$ and $AC.$ Find $\lambda.$

I am unable to solve the above problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Let P, Q be points on AB and BC respectively such that AP : PB = 1: 2 and BQ : QC = 1: 3.

[image]

QP extended meets DA extended at S and CA extended at R.

$\triangle ASP \sim \triangle BQP$. Then, if BQ = 1, AS = 0.5.

Also, $\triangle RAS \sim \triangle RCQ$. If SA = 0.5 and QC = 3, then RA : RC = ? : ??.

---

[Corrected version]

Let P be a point on AB such that AP : PB = [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjoMB.png) : [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIZTB.png).

[image]

Let Q be a point on AD such that AQ : QD = 1 unit: 3 units.

Let Q’ be a point on BC such that QQ’//AB. Then BQ’ = 1 unit and Q’C = 3 units.

PQ cuts AC at S. Extend QP to cuts CB extended at T.

$\triangle APQ \sim\triangle BPT$ implies TB = 2 units. Hence, T C = 6 units.

$\triangle ASQ \sim \triangle CST$ implies AS : SC = AQ : TC = ? :？？

Comment: You have cut AB and BC while the question asks AB and AD.

Comment: @Sid Thanks for pointing that out. Using the original statement, I think the problem is even easier to solve. See the corrected version.

Comment: It does seem so:)